# FactoryGirl creating factories objects on start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

For some reason, when I run

```
rspec specs
```

The models defined on Factory girl are automatically created.
I was expecting to create the objects with sentences like:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

But I am having a lot of duplication problems due to this.

Moreover, if I go to the rails console and I type:

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'
```

It inserts some records on my database.

Is this expected behavior?

UPDATE:
The problem was on my factory (silly mistake). I was calling create method there.

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :user do 
    email "user@example2.com" 
    first_name "Myname"
    last_name "MyLast name"
    password "DoeDoe12" 
    api_license FactoryGirl.create(:api_license)
  end 
end
```

Comment: Instead commenting it, answer your own question and select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not. Are you sure these records are created by FactoryGirl?

Make sure you are not loading seeds or fixtures. If you empty the /factories folder and the records are still created, then the culprit is someone else.

Comment: It was a silly mistake. Your answer was helpful, I will mark it as correct soon.